# Reference type inside value type

Tags: swift, memory-management, value-type, reference-type, deinit

I am exploring Swift value types particularly structs to get a better understanding of it's uses in different scenario. I was amazed to see how enum can be used to build Binary Search Tree using `indirect` which introduces a thin layer of reference semantics.

```
enum BinarySearchTree<T: Comparable> {
  case empty
  case leaf(T)
  indirect case node(BinarySearchTree, T, BinarySearchTree)
}
```

Now coming to real question, what I am struggling to find is, what will happen to reference type inside a value type. How will the relationship work? like memory management, Object lifecycle.

For e.g.

```
class B {
    var data: Int = 0

    deinit {
        print("deallocated!")
    }

}

struct A {
    var b = B()
}
```

In the above case, a value type holds a reference to a reference type.

1. When will `deinit` will get called?
2. Does every new struct instance of type `A` will have reference to same instance of class `B` or will they be different.
3. What should I need to take care of or it is a code smell?
4. Anything else?

Comment: Consider that a reference *itself* is a value type – it (but not the *instance* it points to) gets copied when you pass it about. So you're already somewhat familiar with the semantics :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every struct `A` *copy* will share the *same* reference to `B`. Every *new* struct `A`, created from scratch, will hold a completely new `B` object.

The `B.deint` will be called when there are zero *[strong references](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)* to it (e.g., your `var b` is one of these strong references). For instance, if only `A` values hold references to a given `B` object then those will need to got out of scope to zero all references to this object (or their *boxed copies* be deallocated as well, but this might be a topic for another question.)

**Code Design**. If these all sounds too confusing and is blocking your app progress (with no real practical benefit so far), you might consider refactoring `B` to a struct as well. For instance, even [Apple recommends considering value types](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) to design your *model layer*. [This blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) might also help make up your mind.

Comment: How to make a value go out of scope after creating it?

Comment: @Rahul For instance, if you declare a `var a: A = ...` inside a function, then when that function returns the `a` value will go out of scope. Makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

You can test this in a playground:

```
class B {
    var data: Int = 0

    deinit {
        print("deallocated!")
    }
}

struct A {
    var b = B()
}

var a1: A? = A()
var a2: A? = A()
var a3: A? = a1

// Do the two instances of struct A share the same instance of class B?
a1?.b === a2?.b // false

// Do copies of instances of struct A share the same instance of class B?
a1?.b === a3?.b // true

// When will deinit be called?
a1 = nil    // Not yet, a3 still holds a strong reference to the shared instance of class B
a3 = nil    // Now! There are no longer any strong references to the shared instance of class B, so it is deallocated.
```

Comment: `Are the instances of class B the same?` => Only because you allocated 2 new `A` instances. If `a2` was created by copying from `a1` (via assignment), then they'll reference the same `b`.

Comment: Now you'll need to `nil` out `a3`, because it contains a strong reference that will preserve `a1`'s `b`, even after `a1` is `nil`

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! My mistake - I hope this answer is useful despite its edits.